# What could be an electronic way to verify that someone is from a specific university department or university?

Tags: university

How could I verify that a person is a student/faculty/researcher at a specific department of any university in world?  I could ask the user to verify the official email address provided by that university to him but not all universities in world provide a email address to their people. A considerably large percentage of universities do not provide.

What could be other ways to collect only verified people in some group for a university department ?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to do this verification?

Comment: Actually on a website, I need to allow only people access only to *their  actual university department*.

Comment: You mean you have a website which has a section for each of certain departments, and you need to make sure only faculty of a given department can access the given section?

Comment: Yes I want to allow anyone(student or a faculty) verified  from a university department to access that restricted section for that department.

Comment: BTW, could you give an example of a university that does not provide an email? I have never heard of that (a bigger problem is that often people will be allowed to keep their email long after they are no longer affiliated with the university).

Comment: In India, there are many such. Good to know that it's not a worry case (..for US, right?)

Comment: But I would have a global audience, so I need to take care of those universities who don't provide email to their students/faculty.

Comment: "but not all universities in world provide a email address to their people" - and others do provide e-mail addresses also to people who are not, in the strict sense, "their people" (and not only in the case alluded to by @TobiasKildetoft).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Some exemplary arrangements that I've seen: People located at a university (given an office there), but actually financed based on a starbust programme, so they are not formally employees of the university. They are, for all intents and purposes, part of the department, and yet, they don't get a university e-mail address because their arrangement circumvents uni administration and thus systems administration will not provide an e-mail address. Same for people who formally belong to two departments (though only one officially). Likewise, guest researchers who stay for a year.

Comment: @Buffy You are cleaning up lots of (very) old postings with minor edits. It's nice to have everything nice, but the edits put the questions on the active question queue; I wonder if there's a way to avoid that.

Comment: @EthanBolker, My edits are just tag maintenance. There are some recent Meta questions on this with discussion. See: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5087/75368, and https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5066/75368. In particular [tag:students] is now deprecated and old questions are being updated bit by bit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good *fully automated* way of doing this, because there is no central clearing-house are too many ways the humans maintain imprecise machine-readable records.

If you are willing to have a human process, you can deal with a lot of the problem cases with a combination of Google and phone calls.  That still won't ensure that an institution that you personally aren't familiar with is real, given all of the [diploma mills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_mill) in the world, but it will at least reduce the likelihood of giving access to a legitimate institution to the wrong person.

Comment: A phone call can verify that John Smith is a student at Foobar University -- but it can't verify that the person trying to register on your site is actually John Smith.  Also, this doesn't seem likely to work on a large scale - after the 50th phone call to the Foobar Registrar Office, I expect they're going to quit taking your calls.

Answer (score 1):

If:

- the university has an https website whose certificate has a chain of signatures back to a certificate authority you trust; and
- members of the university have authority to edit their own profiles on that https website; and
- you're confident that the university's IT security is good enough to stop third parties from editing university members' profile pages,

then the following might do the job:

- the person whose identity you're trying to verify creates an authenticated-PGP private/public key pair linked to an e-mail address they do have;
- they place the public key on their profile page on the university's https website;
- you obtain the public key from the https website;
- they then send you a cryptographically signed e-mail;
- you verify the signature;
- now you can be confident that the e-mail came from the same person whose profile page bears the public key.